# Django shell printing everything twice

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have something that is happening in my django shell that I cannot explain and do not know how to fix;

```
def get_answer_dict(self, format = None, *args,**kwargs):
    current_user = MyUser.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['pk2']) #current_user
    print(current_user)
    survey_team = Survey.objects.get(name= 'Survey Raphael') #survey team (to change to final one)
    current_response = ResponseModel.objects.filter(user = current_user, survey = survey_team)[0] #current response
    #print(current_response)
    answer_list = current_response.answers.all()
    #print(answer_list)
    answer_dict = []
    for answer in answer_list:
        ans_body =  answer.body
        ans_json = json.loads(ans_body)
        answer_dict.append(ans_json)
    return answer_dict
```

The thing is that in my django shell the user is printed twice... 
Do you have an idea why ?

[image]

Comment: Obviously you are calling `get_answer_dict` twice, or from 2 different places, could you provide more explanation and code please? In this state of the question i dont think that anybody could help. Thanks!

Comment: look on your `__str__` method